# Runtime error 438 when assigning 1 of 2 worksheet variables

Tags: excel, vba

I am losing my mind here, I appreciate help understanding what is going on.

I'm writing a macro to prompt the user to open a datafile and then to open a report to populate the data to. The macro is launched via ActiveX button from a 3rd xlsm workbook (just like all of my other macros).

I am doing this with 2 separate FileDialog Objects. Once I have both workbooks opened and assigned to variables, I pass them ByVal to a sub that is supposed to do the work. The first step in the sub is to assign the worksheet variables for both workbooks. The first worksheet variable assigns properly, but the 2nd worksheet variable keeps giving me the "RTE 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method".

I am writing this macro based off a previous one I wrote that had a similar flow of opening 2 workbooks (but with one FileDialog object), passing them to a sub, then operating on them.

I know that my workbooks are not the issue, as my old macro works when I load my current report/data workbooks. I've also tried opening 2 test workbooks in my current macro and it still fails with the same message as before. Something is going on in the code but I really have no clue at this point, I've been on this for 2 days now. My current macro up to this point is basically a copy/paste of the older one that somehow works.

Random things I've tried:

- Copy macro into new .bas file, delete old one
- Combine the 2 FileDialog objects into 1 (mimicking old macro)
- restart excel
- rename variables
- setting first filedialog object=nothing before running 2nd filedialog object

Here's my code on the sheet tied to button.click()

```
    Dim data_Path As String, report_Path As String
    Dim getData As FileDialog
    Dim getReport As FileDialog
    Dim Data_wb As Workbook
    Dim Report_wb As Workbook

    'Prompt User open data file
    Set getData = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    With getData
        .Title = "Select the new data file."
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Files", "*.xlsx; *.csv", 1
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            data_Path = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

'Set data workbook variable
    Set Data_wb = Workbooks.Open(data_Path)

   'Prompt user to open Report 
    Set getReport = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    With getReport
        .Title = "Select the destination report."
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Files", "*.xlsx; *.csv", 1
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            report_Path = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    Set Report_wb = Workbooks.Open(report_Path)

    Call report_update(Data_wb, Report_wb)
```

Here is the code for report_update sub:

```
Dim datash As Worksheet
Dim reportsh As Worksheet
Dim mydatawb As Workbook
Dim myreportwb As Workbook

sub report_update(ByVal mydatawb as Workbook, ByVal myreportwb as Workbook)
set datash = mydatawb.Worksheets(1)
set reportsh = myreportwb.Worksheets(1)
```

Set datash works fine, but Set reportsh throws the run-time error.

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Does it also generate an error if you step through the code?

Comment: Yes, it still errors. I just moved the worksheets variable declaration to before the Sub call, then passed the worksheet reference rather than workbook. that fixed it for some reason. I'm still confused but at least I can make progress now.

Comment: I find it strange that you have a line saying `Report_Path = .SelectedItems(1)`.  The VBE should have changed the case of `Report_Path` to match what is in the declaration, i.e. to be `report_Path`.  Something very weird there.  Do you have any `On Error Resume Next` statements in your code?

Comment: @YowE3K - good eye, I tried to catch all of those. I manually edited the code and variable names here in the comment editor to reduce the size and make it easier to read. Accidentally missed that one.
EDIT: Edited my question to fix the variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved my Set worksheet objects to before my sub call and passed the worksheet references in rather than the workbook. That seems to have fixed it, I just don't understand why as I've never had to do that before.